# Adding ArcGIS Feature Service connections to QGIS 3 using Python API?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am trying to deploy multiple ArcGIS Feature Service connections to all of the QGIS 3 users in my workplace.

Is there a way to do it using the Python API?

At the moment I'm manually adding the connections into the QGIS3.ini, like this :

```
[qgis]
connections-arcgisfeatureserver\My%20Service%20Name\url=https://services.somewhere.com/arcgis/rest/services/My_Service_Name/MapServer
ARCGISFEATURESERVER\My%20Service%20Name\username=MyUsername
ARCGISFEATURESERVER\My%20Service%20Name\password=MyPassword
ARCGISFEATURESERVER\My%20Service%20Name\authcfg=
```

but I would prefer to add them using Python if possible.

Comment: You can find the answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158087/loading-a-wfs-layer-using-pyqgis). There is lot of expalanations available for adding WFS layer in QGIS. This might help you.

Answer (score 5):

See [qgis.core.QgsSettings](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsSettings.html?highlight=qgssettings)

Instantiate `QgsSettings()` in the QGIS console and you can access all the settings as keys/values

For ArcGIS FeatureServer, try:

```
[i for i in QSettings().allKeys() if 'arcgisfeatureserver' in i]
```

which will show all the keys for the featureserver settings.

For each feature service `[SERVICENAME]` and parameter `[PARAM]` the key `[KEY]` will be in the form:

```
'qgis/connections-arcgisfeatureserver/[SERVICENAME]/[PARAM]'
```

Which you can set using `QgsSettings().setValue([KEY], [VALUE])`

So for your feature service you would have

```
QgsSettings().setValue('qgis/connections-arcgisfeatureserver/[SERVICENAME]/url', [URL])
QgsSettings().setValue('qgis/connections-arcgisfeatureserver/[SERVICENAME]/username', [USERNAME])
QgsSettings().setValue('qgis/connections-arcgisfeatureserver/[SERVICENAME]/password', [PASSWORD])
QgsSettings().setValue('qgis/connections-arcgisfeatureserver/[SERVICENAME]/authcfg', '')
```

Then update the GUI with

```
iface.reloadConnections()
```

I think PyQt's `QSettings()` does the same thing too.

Comment: This solution has worked for me. It should be marked as the correct solution.